# Run .NET Core container under service account

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, containers, windows-authentication

Currently I am running a .NET 4.5 application over IIS. The application runs under service account using app pool. When the application makes connection with SQL server, system is able to pass this service account as the user and able to establish connection.

Now I a want to move over to .NET Core and run my application over container and still want to support service accounts for connecting to SQL server. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some helpful guides:

https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2020/06/23/deploying-an-aspnet-core-web-applications-to-docker/
(shows with or without IIS)

https://blog.wicktech.net/windows-containers-and-iis/